# make buttons behind view not clickable

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have a linear view in front of some buttons with a background and my problem is that I can still click the buttons on the back of the view even though I can't see them. is there a way I can make the view "solid" so I won't be able to click through its background/borders?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not just deleting the buttons but one way you can go about it is disenabling the buttons from your java file using

`myButton.setEnabled(false);`

or in your xml file using:

```
    <Button
android:enabled="false"
/>
```

Comment: I'm basically putting something like a little info thing when you push one of the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I just made the view clickable thus making it "solid" and stopping anyone from clicking stuff behind it

Comment: mark your answer as the correct answer by clicking the green correct mark on the left to close this question